# Byte Array to Image then display in DialogBox C++

Tags: visual-c++

as the title says, ive got this packet which contains the whole JPEG image file, so i've put that into a byte array, now how do i convert this to an image and then display it.

I dont need to save it, just display it then once the user enters an answer, delete it.
If you're wondering, its a captcha image. Something like what JDownloader does with captchas.

edit: i meant how can i display images in dialog boxes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GDI+ Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this, using an [`IStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of your JPEG in memory as the input, which can be done using [`ISequentialStream::Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).